# Background-position with an offset doesn't work

Tags: css

The background-position rule below doesn't work and isn't even visible in Firebug as if the browser considered it a mistake:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/bg_image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% bottom 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying offset edges, you need to specify both of them, even if one of them is the default:

```
background-position: left 50% bottom 10px;
```